# App stops responding to touches after popping a view controller containing an ARKit scene view

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a navigation controller containing a root view controller which contains a single UIButton. Tapping the button pushes another view controller on to the stack. This second view controller contains an ARKit sceneView (ARSCNView).  Inside the scene, I add a node using an SCNPlane, and set the plane's material's diffuse contents to use a view backed by a view controller like so:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class SceneViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
    }

    func setupScene() {
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

        // add a small plane at the origin...
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)

        // create a view controller, and add use its view as the plane's material contents...
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = vc.view

        let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
}
```

When I pop this view controller (using either the back button, or the pan gesture), the root view controller stops responding to touch events.

Rotating the device to landscape, and then back to portrait does seem to free up whatever is causing this behaviour

I've tried overriding touchesBegan on the root view controller, but it doesn't get triggered.

I've tried forcing the window to become first responder.

I've ensured that the SceneViewController is being destroyed, and that the sceneView's session is not still running after the view controller has been destroyed.

This problem doesn't occur when using a UIView, or a UIImage generated from the content view controller's view, but this would mean the it can't be interacted with.

Here's a link to a sample project.  It needs to be run on an ARKit capable device: https://github.com/duncanlowrie/vc-node-test

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same issue. It turns out that if you assign an SKScene to the plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents, this behaviour goes away, but you need the UIView (as do I) for obvious reasons.

Also, I think only about two thirds of the screen becomes unresponsive. I tried it on an iPhone 7 and iPhone XS and if you try to interact with whatever is on the bottom third of your screen, it should work. Ugly bug.

Tried as well to reinstantiate the AppDelegate's window's rootViewController with a fresh entrypoint from the Storyboard: no joy.

Comment: We are seeing the same thing that part of the screen does not respond to touches.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* I think whenever UIView are directly attached to SCNMaterial and    
that SCNMaterial to SCNNode. SCNMaterial are still being used when  
previous screen is visited. By resetting ARSCNView seems to resolve the  
issue. */

import UIKit
import ARKit


class SceneViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //do not set setupScene function here 
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //set setupScene function here
    setupScene()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    //reset ARSCNView before going back to previous screen
    self.sceneView = ARSCNView()
}


func setupScene() {
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

    // add a small plane at the origin...
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)

    // create a view controller, and add use its view as the plane's    material contents...
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = vc.view

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add more explanation?

Comment: @zmag I think whenever UIView are directly attached to SCNMaterial and that SCNMaterial to SCNNode. SCNMaterial are still being used when previous screen is visited. By resetting ARSCNView seems to resolve the issue.